# Create a box with a package? (image)

Tags: tcolorbox, mdframed

Hello I would like to make this type of box, I don't know how to do it, does anyone have a solution?
[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks a bit like the `bclogo` package

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You could probably use tcolorbox for the border on the left.  The frame around the sumation can be done with `\fbox`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'm actually more interested in how to make the symbols on the left side.I think I need to use the Tikz package

Answer (score 2):

For me, it looks like some path morphing with proper line width and segment length in decorations library using `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
enhanced,
frame empty,
title=Example,
sharp corners,
colback=yellow!30,
fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
boxrule=0pt,
detach title,
before upper={\tcbtitle\\[1ex]},
coltitle=black,
fontupper=\sffamily,
overlay={
\path[draw=YellowOrange,decorate,line width=2mm,
decoration={coil,aspect=0,segment length=3mm}]
(frame.north west) -- (frame.south west);}
]
This is an \textbf{Example}.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
enhanced,
frame empty,
title=\faExclamationTriangle\space Attention,
sharp corners,
colback=red!10,
fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
boxrule=0pt,
detach title,
before upper={\tcbtitle\\[1ex]},
coltitle=black,
fontupper=\sffamily,
overlay={
\path[draw=red!30,decorate,line width=2mm,
decoration={saw,segment length=2.75mm}]
(frame.north west) -- (frame.south west);}
]
This is an \textbf{Attention}.

{\vspace{2ex}\centering\fboxsep=4pt\fbox{\parbox{1.65cm}{$\displaystyle
\sum_{i\in\oslash}\mathrm{a}_i=0.$}}\par}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this is exactly what I wanted. If you have any resources for learning TikZ and hopefully reach your level one day, I am interested. Thank you again :)

Comment: @Abichouuu I think the manual is the best, if you take some time to read. https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf